# How can I access a property within an attribute using Razor/Webforms syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to set a maximum length limit in a text area using a regex validator (if there is a better way to do this, please let me know). This is an ASP.Net webforms user control. The current code I have is

```
<asp:Panel ID="labeledTextBox" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="label" CssClass="label" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"/>
    <asp:TextBox ID="textBox" CssClass="labeledTextBox" TextMode="MultiLine" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"/>
    <asp:Label ID="textBoxLengthLabel" CssClass="textBoxLengthLabel" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">Maximum <%= MaxLength %> characters</asp:Label>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="textboxLengthValidator" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="textBox" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,<%= MaxLength %>}$" ErrorMessage="Test Message" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

`MaxLength` is defined in the codebehind file as

```
public int MaxLength { get; set; }
```

The value I set shows up in the `textBoxLengthLabel` properly as, for example, `Maximum 500 characters`.

However, it is taken literally in the attribute for the validator. The markup on the client side is

```
<SPAN id=textboxLengthValidator
      style="COLOR: red; DISPLAY: inline"
      controltovalidate="textBox"
      errormessage="Test Message"
      validationexpression="^[\s\S]{0,<%= MaxLength %>}$"
      isvalid="false"
      display="Dynamic">Test Message</SPAN>
```

How can I use the property in the code-behind file in the attribute?

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind on the page load or on submit you can simply add the atribute

```
textBox.Attributes.Add("maxlength",  MaxLength.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't need a "maxlength" attribute. I need the `validationexpression` to take the field as part of the value. I could do something similar on the validator itself serverside, but I'd like to know if there is a way to do it in the markup.

Comment: Not sure what you mean you mant to validate like in validationexpression on the client side?

Comment: I ultimately want to limit the `textBox` control to `n` characters. Because I could not find a `TextLengthValidator` control, I figured the next best thing would be a regex validator. I want this control to be reusable, so I want to allow for different max lengths. I have the MaxLength property in the code-behind file, yet I am unable to get the value of that property if I access it within an attribute, yet have no problem if it's by itself (like in the `textBoxLengthLabel` control.